# Two-port network: find fundamental parameters

Tags: capacitance, resistance, inductance

[image]

What is the easiest method to find the [ABCD parameters](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=abcd+parameters)?

I tried replacing the middle part of the circuit (R2,L,C) with an equivalent impedance and then finding U2 depending on U1, but it is very time-consuming. Is there a better way?

Maybe considering this circuit as a cascade connection of three two-port networks (R1 ; L,R2,C ; R3)?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no magic approach to this: these kind of "ladder" circuits (that's a name I invented right now) are always a pain.

I would transform the triangle R2, L, C in a star using the [Y-\$\Delta\$ transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) (that's actually a \$\Delta\$-Y transform in your case), so that the circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmevcQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now of course you can compute the series R1, Z1 and R3, Z3 that leaves you with a T network that is probably already solved in literature.

Comment: I think cascading those 3 "separate" two-port network is quite fast, only have to know the abcd parameters for PI network and then multiply those 3 matrices. Am I right?

Comment: No, that won't work because of loading effects.

Comment: Because of the capacitor and the coil? I was taught that as long as I know the ABCD matrix, I only have to multiply them, no matter how the 2-port networks look.

Comment: You are perfectly right, cascading works charmlessly as you said with ABCD parameters. Your first idea is the bes indeed.

Comment: But what did you mean by loading effects, if I may ask?

Comment: Of course you may ask! The point is that if you have a two port network, calculate its parameters, then connect a load to it you can't expect to the values computated to hold since the load changes the parameters. With ABCD these effect, called loading effect, is accounted just by multiplying.

Comment: By the way, which software do you recommend for checking my answers (I would like if I could only draw the scheme, write the complex values for the impedance and the current is shown in a complex form as well)?